# Multinomial Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: r, bayesian, multinomial, naivebayes

I have been looking for a multinomial naive Bayes classifier on CRAN, and so far all I can come up with is the binomial implementation in package `e1071`. Does anyone know of a package that has a multinomial Bayes classifier?

Comment: Have you tried `NaiveBayes()` in the `klaR` package? I haven't used it, but I know it's an extension on the version in `e1071`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll see if it implements a multinomial classifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bnlearn not doing it for you? http://www.bnlearn.com/

Is on CRAN, and claims to implement "naive Bayes" network classifiers and "Discrete (multinomial) data sets are supported".

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'll test it out and see if it works for multinomial data. Unfortunately `bnlearn` doesn't support compressed sparse matrices as input, but I can deal with that.

Comment: When I look at the bnlearn docs, I do not see an option to use a multinomial likelihood estimate for features. It says the features are assumed to be Gaussian distributed. Am I reading something wrong here?